# DSCP carryforward from downstream to upstream path by envoy

Tags: envoyproxy

DSCP can be set by setsockopt(IP_TOS) from application. But after going through sidecar/envoy, DSCP is not set in upstream path using DSCP in IP header from downstream. Of course even we can set it in Cluster using bindConfig but it is static configured instead of using DSCP value from downstream ip header.

So is there any way envoy can carryforward the DSCP from downstream to upstream path?

Thanks,